# How do I extract data between HTML tags using Regex?

Tags: regex

I've been assigned some sed homework in my class and am one step away from finishing the assignment.  I've racked my head trying to come up with a solution and nothing's worked to the point where I'm about to give up.

Basically, in the file I've got...I'm supposed to replace this:

```
<b>Some text here...each bold tag has different content...</b>
```

with

```
Some text here...each bold tag has different content...
```

I've got it partially completed, but what I can't figure out is how to "echo" the extracted content using sed (regexp).

I manage to substitute the content out just fine, but it's when I'm trying to actually OUTPUT the content that's between the HTML tags that it goes wrong.

If that's confusing, I truly apologize.  I've been at this project a couple hours now and am getting a bit frusturated.  Basically, why does this not work?

```
s/<b>.*<\/b>/.*/g
```

I simply want to output the content WITHOUT the bold tags.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This is homework? Wow. Please point your tutor at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference a part of your regex match in the replacement, you need to place that portion of the regex into a capturing group, and then refer to it using the group number preceded by a backslash.  Try the following:

```
s/<b>\(.*\)</b>/\1/g
```

Comment: The lazy quantifier isn't supported in sed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capturing group, which are parentheses ()

So, it's just this:

```
s/<b>(.*)<\/b>/\1/g
```

Capturing groups are numbered, from left to right, starting with one, and increasing.

This syntax is the standard way to do regular expressions; sed's syntax is slightly different. the sed command is

```
sed 's/<b>\(.*\)<\/b>/\1/g' [file]
```

or

```
sed -r 's/<b>(.*)<\/b>/\1/g' [file]
```

Of course, if you just want to remove the bold tags, the other solution would be to just replace the HTML tags with blanks like so

```
sed 's/<\([^>]\|\(\"[^\"]\"\)\)*>//g' [file]
```

(I dislike sed's need to escape everything)

```
s/<([^\]|(\"[^\"]\"))*>//g
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this question should be addressed to SED's mans. Like this: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4

Comment: Ah, the good old rtfm.  The asker just didn't know about capturing groups, or how to search for them.